# Laravel & C# Application API Issue

Tags: c#, laravel, api

We have an application (C#) that up till today has worked fine.
It communicates with a laravel website to manage the sites data.

So there are some validation points that occur, the application does checks with out SSO provider for authentication.  Then it passes some of the user's information over to the site so the site can create a user / send back user id for further entry points.

I have literally not touched this in months - and its been working without a problem.

Today I get a message its not working and so I start digging.

Can somebody explain THIS one?

C# Code For Validating User -  Notice the response from the site.

[image]

The Laravel API Routes File on the route in question.

[image]

```
public function validation(Request $request) {
    //Check if user exists if they do then just return.  If they dont we need to create them in the system.
    $user = User::where('email', $request['Email'])->first();
    if($user == null) {
        $nuser = new User();
        $nuser->first_name = $request['FName'];
        $nuser->last_name = $request['LName'];
        $nuser->email = $request['Email'];
        $nuser->token = $request['Token'];
        
        switch($request['Role']) {
            case 1:
                $nuser->user_level = 1;             
            break;
            case 2:
                $nuser->user_level = 2;             
            break;
            case 3:
                $nuser->user_level = 3;             
            break; 
            case 4: 
                $nuser->user_level = 4;
            break;
            default:
                $nuser->user_level = 4;
            break;
        }
        try {
            $nuser->save();
            return json_encode($nuser);
        }catch(\Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }else{
        switch($request['Role']) {
            case 1:
                $user->user_level = 1;              
            break;
            case 2:
                $user->user_level = 2;              
            break;
            case 3:
                $user->user_level = 3;              
            break; 
            case 4: 
                $user->user_level = 4;
            break;
            default:
                $user->user_level = 4;
            break;
        }
        try {
            $user->save();
            return json_encode($user);
        }catch(\Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although you are frustrated, try to avoid the ranting. Is the server perhaps responding with a 302 redirect to the initial POST request and then the following GET rest (that RestSharp automatically follows) is blocked? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46532226/3034273) for how to disable RestSharp's `RestClient` from automatically following redirects.

Comment: If `public function validation()` in `UserController` is triggering a redirect (a `GET` request), you can sometimes see that happening. Can you include the contents of these `UserController` functions? (`validation`, to me, seems to be the most likely culprit)

Comment: Added the function code.

Comment: What's the status code you are receiving in the response? Also you share the entire response Content in the question?

Comment: So the end user of the C# application decided to overwrite the ini file with the website in it (for quick swaps between dev and production for the development team)....I noticed new entries in the development server's database from yesterday asked if anybody on dev did it...nope....end user then tries to put it back to the production server.  But left off the s in https - and like any good website - it auto redirects to its https counterpart.

@Xerillio - if you'll just post an answer about the redirects I'll mark it as the answer because that was ultimately the problem.

Comment: @JamesF Thanks, but to be fair the problem sounds more like a typo problem rather than wrong RestClient configuration. I think you should either post your own solution as an answer (you can answer your own question) or this is a duplicate of the question I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

So the end user of the C# application decided to overwrite the ini file with the website in it (for quick swaps between dev and production for the development team)....I noticed new entries in the development server's database from yesterday....end user then tries to put it back to the production server.  But left off the s in https - and like any good website - it auto redirects to its https counterpart.

Cue RestClient trying to follow the redirect with a GET.
Updated the INI fixing the typo, tell user to close the application and reopen it to reload the INI data. Have our network team lock down the network folder containing the INI to read only unless its a member of the development team. And we're back rolling.